# Validating Python list indexing syntax with ECMAScript regex

Tags: python, c++, regex, c++11

I am writing a C++ code that takes a string as an input and checks if that string has a valid Python list indexing syntax. For example:

`a[0]`, `a[:]`, `a[::]`, `a[0:]`, `a[-1::]`, `a[  2 :  1:2]` `a[:  -1:]`, `a[::-  1]`, `a[1:10:2]`, and so on.

So far I've got the following regular expression:

```
^[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*\[([ ]*-?[ ]*[0-9]+[ ]*)*:?([ ]*-?[ ]*[0-9]+[ ]*)*:?([ ]*-?[ ]*[0-9]+[ ]*)*\]$
```

However, it looks too long to me and I wonder if there is a better way to do this. Also, the above regular expression will match `a[]` which is undesirable. I have just started experimenting with regular expressions and my knowledge is limited. So my questions are:

- Is the a better way to construct a regex for validating Python list indexing?
- I would like the regex to fail on `a[]`. How can I do that?

I am using C++ 11 regular expressions library which has ECMAScript syntax by default.

Thank you.

Comment: If all you want is *syntactically* valid then you can't know if it's a list or not.  Something like `a['stuff', f(1, 2, 3), a+b.blah]` is syntactically valid.

Comment: Well, it does not look too long, but you may shorten it a bit and add a lookahead to restrict the empty brackets - [`R"(^[_a-zA-Z]\w*\[(?! *\]) *-? *\d*(?: *: *-? *\d*){0,2} *\])"`](https://regex101.com/r/OU9cQB/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
^[_a-zA-Z]\w*\[(?! *\]) *-? *\d*(?: *: *-? *\d*){0,2} *\]$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/OU9cQB/2). The spaces may be replaced with `[[:blank:]]` or `[ \t]` to match horizontal whitespace.

**Pattern details**

- `^` - start of string
- `[_a-zA-Z]` - a `_` or an ASCII letter
- `\w*` - ASCII letters/digits/`_`
- `\[` - a `[`
- `(?! *\])` - there cannot be 0+ spaces followed with `]`
- `*-? *` - 0+ spaces, an optional `-`, 0+ spaces
- `\d*`
- `(?: *: *-? *\d*){0,2}` - zero, one or two occurrenes of:

  - `*: *-? *` - 0+ spaces, an optional `-`, 0+ spaces
  - `\d*` - 0+ digits
- `*]` - 0+ spaces and `]`
- `$` - end of string.

See the [C++ demo](https://ideone.com/i2mYMM) (note that with `regex_match`, the `^` and `$` become redundant and may be omitted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    std::vector<std::string> strings;
    strings.push_back("a[0]");
    strings.push_back("a[:]");
    strings.push_back("a[::]");
    strings.push_back("a[0:]");
    strings.push_back("a[-1::]");
    strings.push_back("a[  2 :  1:2]");
    strings.push_back("a[:  -1:]");
    strings.push_back("a[::-  1]");
    strings.push_back("a[1:10:2]");
    strings.push_back("a[]");

    std::regex rex1(R"([_a-zA-Z]\w*\[(?! *\]) *-? *\d*(?: *: *-? *\d*){0,2} *\])");
    for (auto s : strings)
    {
        std::cout << "Next string: " << s;
        if (regex_match(s, rex1)) {
            std::cout << "<= Matched" << std::endl;
        } else {
            std::cout << "<= Not Matched" << std::endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Next string: a[0]<= Matched
Next string: a[:]<= Matched
Next string: a[::]<= Matched
Next string: a[0:]<= Matched
Next string: a[-1::]<= Matched
Next string: a[  2 :  1:2]<= Matched
Next string: a[:  -1:]<= Matched
Next string: a[::-  1]<= Matched
Next string: a[1:10:2]<= Matched
Next string: a[]<= Not Matched
```

Comment: Hello my friend. Very nice explanation! I wonder if you could also modify the proposed solution to not match `a[-]` and numbers that start with zeros, e.g., `a[01]`, `a[2:003]`, `a[02:-001:0003]`, etc. Thank you.

Comment: PS: I a going to accept your answer regardless if you address this additional request or not, if no better answer shows up really soon.

Comment: @AstrOne  See [`^[_a-zA-Z]\w*\[(?![ -]*\]) *-? *(?!0+[1-9])\d*(?: *: *-? *(?!0+[1-9])\d*){0,2} *\]$`](https://regex101.com/r/OU9cQB/3).

Comment: @AstrOne Glad to help, just to explain: `(?![ -]*\])` fails the match if, after `[`, there are only spaces or hyphens up to the `]`, and `(?!0+[1-9])` negative lookahead fails all matches with 1 or more `0` chars followed with a digit from `1` to `9` after the current position (that is, all `\d*` cannot match numbers starting with `0`).